# setcolor not working in custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to change text color when click on list item.

I have created selector file in res/color/textcolor_selector , but textcolor is not changed when click on textview

below is my code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            textView.setText(listArr[position]);

            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor_selector));
```

textcolor_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/selectedcolor"  />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/selectedcolor" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/selectedcolor" />
<item android:color="@color/nonselectedcolor" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I think you should be using ``getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.textcolor_selector)`` for setTextColor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing one color only;

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor_selector)
```

You should pass ColorStateList instead;

```
getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.textcolor_selector)
```

In your current implementation you're calling `TextView.setTextColor(int)` method instead of `.setTextColor(ColorStateList)`.